# A "strange" (maybe "extreme" or "crazy") approach to test by using Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, cucumber

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, cucumber-rails-1.3.0, rspec-rails-2.8.1, capybara-1.1.2 and factory_girl-2.6.3. I have a Scenario that tests the user sign up like the following:

```
Scenario: I register an user
  When I fill in "Name" with "Foo"
  And I fill in "Email" with "foo_bar@email.com"
  And I fill in "Password" with "test_password"
  And I click button "Register"
  Then I should be redirected to the homepage
```

and I am trying to state a new Feature (within a separated file) where to implement a Scenario that, by using a token, should test the signed up user confirmation process to be properly completed (*note*: in reality, this process involves an email message delivering but I do *not* want to test if that email was sent; just ignore it for this question). Since I would like to test exclusively the confirmation process, I thought to implement a new Feature/Scenario where to state something like `Given I am a registered user` for which to run the `Scenario: I register an user`.

```
Scenario: I confirm an user
  Given I am a registered user # Here I would like to run the 'Scenario: I register an user'
  When I go to the confirmation page
  And I enter the confirmation token
  Then ...
```

In few words, *I thought to call an entire Scenario within another Scenario*.

Even if I can use the FactoryGirl gem to "create"-"register" an user, I prefer to proceed with the above approach because I'd tests ("practically" speaking, those "represent" "invisible people" that, managed by the Selenium gem, open my browser and perform actions) to behave as much as possible like "real people" behave, and so those test steps to implicitly follow all "real" steps that should be made in reality in order to sign up a new user. By following this approach I can test whether or not the application "interiors" are properly working.

**Is it a correct approach? If no, how could/should I proceed?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the principles of well designed tests is that you exercise a particular feature in all of its various forms, but beyond that presume it to be working within the context of other tests that are exercising other features. That is, once you've tested that users can register, you should not be re-testing the same thing unless you're testing it in a different way.

The phrasing "Given I am a registered user" is something that implies the user has already successfully registered. You shouldn't go testing registration at this point since that's outside the scope of the test you're trying to perform.

Each test should have a mandate and it should stick to it. If you don't limit yourself your tests will spiral into a uselessly inter-dependent mess where changing one thing requires changing every other thing hooked in to it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to run a scenario within a step is:

```
Given /^I authenticate successfully$/ do
  Given 'I am on the login page'
  And 'I fill in "Email" with "eddie@hotmail.com"'
  And 'I fill in "Password" with "secret"'
  When 'I press "Login"'
  Then 'I should see "Welcome"'
end
```

Final thoughts: In general, have your Feature file not have any "fill in" --- just have it describe the actions, and have your steps do the dirty work.